# Django logging does not work inside views and viewsets

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework, view

Can someone please help me understand why django does not print logging messages that I put inside views methods?
When I call logger.debug() from outside views it works correctly

my views.py

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug('THIS LOGGING MESSSAGE SHOWS UP IN LOGS')




class RequestGetResultViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.RequestGetResultSerializer
    queryset = Request.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):]
        logger.debug('THIS LOGGING MESSSAGE DOES NOT SHOW UP')
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user.id) 

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=True, renderer_classes=(PassthroughRenderer,))
    def download(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug('THIS LOGGING MESSSAGE DOES NOT SHOW UP')
        # working code here
        return response
```

my settings.py:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG' ,
    },
   
}
```

Comment: print()  messages do not show in stdout too, if I put print() statements after failed loggers